# Semicolon(;) After Class Constructors or Destructors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am currently maintaining and studying the language using a Legacy Source,I want to clear up some confusion on the use of semi-colons inside a class.

Here is the bit where confusion strikes me.

```
class Base
{
public:
  Base(int m_nVal = -1 ): nVal(m_nVal) {} // Confused here
  virtual ~Base() {} // Confused here
public:
  virtual void SomeMethod();
  virtual int  SomeMethod2();
protected: 
  int nVal;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived(int m_nVal):nVal2(m_nVal) {}; // Confused here
  virtual ~Derived(){}; // Confused here
public:
  virtual void SomeMethod();
  virtual int SomeMethod2();
protected:/* Correction Here */
  int nVal2;
};
```

I have noticed that some of the class destructors/constructors have a Semi-colon after them and some of them don't, I do understand that the a semi-colon is a is a statement terminator. My question is does the Semi-colon after the constructors or destructor tells something specific to the compiler? or is it something that doesn't really matter.

Comment: Semicolons after function bodies are considered their own (empty) statements. They are not part of the function body itself.

Comment: No, `;` is redundant here. And there can be no statements outside functions; in this case it's an empty declaration, I believe.

Comment: you can't study C++ by reading source code. There are multiple rules and nuances that are only implied by code. Also, if code is "legacy" you might see an  old , outdated usage inherited from old versions.

Comment: Or other dodgy stuff like a base and a derived class both having a variable with the same name. The two `nVal`s are two different variables and Derived will have both of them, but `Base::nVal` is hidden by `Derived::nVal` and harder to access.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile because `Base::SomeMethod2` and `Derived::SomeMethod2` have different return types, so technically it's not valid C++ code so a few extra semicolons are whatever

Comment: `Base::nVal` will also be initialized to `-1` in the `Derived` class which probably cause no end of confusion to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the Semi-colon after the constructors or destructor tells something specific to the compiler?

After (or before) a member function definition it does not.†
After (but not before) a member function declaration it is mandatory.
'Probably just an oversight.

†: Unless the definition has no body:

```cpp
struct A { 
  A() = default; // Mandatory semicolon. Definition
  ~A() {}        // Accessory semicolon. Definition
  void foo();    // Mandatory semicolon. Declaration
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The `{}` at the end of the function `Base(int m_nVal = -1 ): nVal(m_nVal) {}` means you have a complete definition of a function, not a mere declaration like `virtual void SomeMethod();`

Perhaps it would be more recognizable when spread out a bit better:

```cpp
Base(int m_nVal = -1 ): 
    nVal(m_nVal) 
{
}
```

Now we can easily see we have the full function definition (with a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to boot) and functions never require a terminating semicolon.

Comment: Thank you very much! That cleared everything up!

Comment: How does that explain why `Base(int m_nVal = -1 ): nVal(m_nVal) {}` and `Base(int m_nVal = -1 ): nVal(m_nVal) {};` are legal?